# MySQL Database Field Decimal Datatype

Tags: mysql

I want to have a number field with two decimal places and 1 decimal place where it could recognizes both 1.1 and 1.10 , 2.2 , 2.20 etc.

I have tried using `Decimal` datatype

```
Create table Number (Sample decimal (3,2);
```

When I try to input `1.1` it outputs `1.10`,  what should I do?

Comment: it would be great to have broader context, why you need distinguish 1.1 and 1.10. Decimal can not do the trick - string field is the only way.

Comment: Handle the presentation in your logic. Whatever language you are using for that

Comment: Don't mess up with types. The suggestion from @juergend is by far the best. Also this is pure mathematics the 1.1 is equals to 1.10 wich is equals to 1.100000000000000000. It would be better if you try to explain why you need this difference!

Answer (score 0):

When you select form the table, check for the second decimal and do the truncate if needed. See the below code:

```
select case when ((1.10*100)%10) > 0 then 1.10 else truncate(1.10, 1) end;
select case when ((1.12*100)%10) > 0 then 1.12 else truncate(1.12, 1) end;
```

You may use it as `select case when ((mydecimalcolumn)%10) > 0 then mydecimalcolumn else truncate(mydecimalcolumn, 1) end mydecimalcolumn, othercolumn1, othercolumn2 from mytable;`